# youtube iframe API- play one video at a time on ajax content

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a webpage. I'm using jQuery load (AJAX) function to dynamically load new content (articles) into the content div. In this div, multiple videos gets loaded. What I want is to play only one youtube video at a time. If one video is in playing state, and the user clicks on another video, the previous one should get paused.  I have used onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() script code for the functionality. The code is working only for the videos that are loaded on first instance. As I scroll down the page, different videos are loaded on page (through AJAX call) and the code doesnot work on new content. Also shows error like:

**TypeError: this.pauseVideo is not a function--
this.pauseVideo();**

I have added the script code below:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
var num = firstScriptTag.length;
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

    var $ = jQuery;
    var players = [];
    $("iframe").filter(function(){
        return this.src.indexOf('https://www.youtube.com/') == 0}).each( function (k, v) {

        var $urls_get=$(this).attr("src");
        var $new_url=$urls_get+"&enablejsapi=1";
        if (!this.id) {
           this.id='embeddedvideoiframe' + k;
           this.src=$new_url;
        }

        players.push(new YT.Player(this.id, {
           events: {
                'onStateChange': function(event) {
                   if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                        $.each(players, function(k, v) {

                            if ('embeddedvideoiframe' + k != event.target.getIframe().id) {
                                    this.pauseVideo();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }))
    });
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should call onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() again with your new data loaded through ajax.